# Squats for lower back pain before

Tags: squats, bodyweight

I am tall close to 6 feet.I was able to do squats with 18kg weights before  like more than 6 months ago and replaced it with running then i left doing exercise for legs.but one day i accidently used my back lifting water can of 20kg and got a pain in back but it was healed.Now i am trying to do squats again without weights but it feels so taxing on my body and i use my feet fingers to lift not the balls of the feet.
Can you give me any progression for squats and any tips to correct my form?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up Dan John's goblet squats, they're pretty good for improving squat technique, and can be loaded very easily once you're ready.

I would also recommend squatting every day to improve technique and get more comfortable with the squatting motion. Also, sit in the bottom position of the squat, using an external object for balance if you need to, and try to move around a bit, it helps to loosen up the hips some.

I'm 6 foot 6 inches tall, and used to really struggle with squats. I manage to dramatically improve my squat technique by

- Squatting in some form every day (need to get something out of a low cupboard, it's an opportunity to practice your squat technique!)
- Sitting in the bottom squat position for 5 minutes every night and "wiggling" back and forth to get more comfortable in the position, and loosen up the hips

Answer (score 1):

I made a video of the common squat progression I use with my rehabilitation clients. https://youtu.be/08i3ZXMuil0

The other tip would be to find a way to do them that is pain free and very slowly increase the difficulty (weight).

I hope you get better soon.